# Replace word in template page with title of page in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am now starting to realize the infinite ways a person can utilize php.

I have created a template page called new-member.php that calls in the content from another page so that when I add a new member, it is fast and easy.

The path I use now is:

1. I add a new page with the company name as the title.
2. I choose the new member template.
3. I Click publish. This creates a "new member coming soon" page that is up in seconds. Perfect!

But I would like to take it to a higher level and have a php function replace "New Member" with the page title (The company name) so that when I add a new page, not only does it have the new members url, but instead of saying "New Member coming soon" it says "XYZ Company Coming Soon!" which is a temporary page until the official one is built.

Could someone please show me the correct code and where to place that code? I am using wordpress. I have no clue how to write this code. Does the code go into the new member.php template? The header? I have no idea but want to learn!

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do there (if I were in your position I would have put together a plugin or do some functions.php hacking) is capture the output of the included page and replace your specific tag "New Member" with what you need. In the below example i'm going to use `%NEW_MEMBER_NAME%` instead of "New Member", which makes your replacement string more unique, so that in your placeholder wp page you will write

"%NEW_MEMBER_NAME% comig soon".

```
<?php /* Template Name: New Member */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php
        the_post();
        // i don't think you need this anymore
        // get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
        ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php if(function_exists('iinclude_page')) {
                ob_start();
                iinclude_page(112);
                $content = ob_get_clean();
                echo str_replace('%NEW_MEMBER_NAME%',the_title('','',false),$content);
            } ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Remember that it's never a good ideea to hardcode things in your templates, as you are doing here with "112", the id of your placeholder wp page, and presumably the replacement tag %NEW_MEMBER_NAME%. 
You should fork the theme, and create an admin options page for these two.

Hope this hepls you in some way.

Comment: Hi moxu, I actually solved it very easily by adding '<a title="<?php the_title();?>' into the page template wherever New Member was. Once I understood page templates, it was pretty easy and I even ended up adding some other php scripting blocks. Love php! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your newmember.php template file. Find 'The Loop'. This is where your post content is shown. Echo the title out.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

```
//syntax
<?php the_title( $before, $after, $echo ); ?> 

//add this to your newmember.php template
<?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>', true); ?>
```

If you post what is in your newmember.php template file then a more specific answer can be provided. But this is simple enough, I think you can probably figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understood your question correct.
But here is what I think you may have to do.

Just replace

```
New Member coming soon
```

with

```
<?php the_title();?> coming soon
```

Now you will get the page title instead of "New Member".

Comment: Here is the code in my newmember.php file

`<?php
/*
Template Name: New Member
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div id="primary">
   <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
      <div class="entry-content">   
     <?php if(function_exists('iinclude_page')) iinclude_page(112); ?>    
    </div>
   </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I couldnt figure out how to implement either one of them though! 

Basically I want to replace all instances of "new member" with the title of the page.

here is a link to a sample page:

[http://www.allaboutparkinglots.com/mistis-paving/]

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: You are using custom theme and without looking full theme code its nearly impossible to say where the title "New Member" is added to the page.

Comment: Hi tamilsweet! I am actually using the twentyeleven theme. I have the plugin improved include page, hence the function "iinclude page" in the member.php. So I am using the member page.php as the template that is including the contennt from page id 112, which is a regular page with all of the text. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are using customized twentyeleven theme. If you can add the code from content-page.php it would be helpful.

Comment: `article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <header class="entry-header">
  <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 </header><!-- .entry-header -->

 <div class="entry-content">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
 </div><!-- .entry-content -->
 <footer class="entry-meta">
  <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>`

Comment: `</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->`

Comment: Hi tamilsweet! Have you been able to look at my code and come up with a solution for me? I am anxious to learn how to do this!

Comment: The codes you gave above were not sufficient. If you need further assistance zip your theme folder and provide link. Without looking full code its not possible to give a solution.

Comment: you can delete them. Will check and reply in few hours.

Comment: tamilsweet... we're you able to come up with a solution for me?

Comment: Hi, no clue in both the templates. I guess you are using custom plugin and its part of its settings. Are you using open source plugin for that ??

Comment: Hi tamilsweet. I am using the plugin Improved Include Page.